# How to dynamically remove and turn back two items from array?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I have two buttons and one array.

Button "OR" and Button "AND" and one Array(Dropdown) which have 7 items.

When you user click on "OR" button there should be removed 2 items from array.

But when user click on "AND" button there should be initial 7 items.

I would try to dynamically add and remove that two items from array. Which is best way to implement that?

Here is HTML of buttons(ruleOperator):

```
<label *ngFor="let ruleOperator of ruleOperatorArray"
       [class.active]="rule.ruleOperator === ruleOperator.value"
       (click)="rule.ruleOperator = ruleOperator.value"
       class="nano-radio-button">
    <span>
        {{ ruleOperator.name }}
    </span>
</label>
```

Here is dropdown and that is on the same page with buttons:
This "arrayOfOptions" is array from which I need to add/remove that items.

```
<nano-drop-down [arrayOfOptions]="audienceRuleTypes"
                [selectedOptions]="rule.ruleClass"
                (selectedOptionsChange)="rule.onRuleChange($event)">
</nano-drop-down>
```

Here is how that array looks:

```
export const RULE_ARRAY = [
    {value: 'SimplePixel', name: 'Simple Pixel Call'},
    {value: 'SearchTerms', name: 'Search Terms'},
    {value: 'DataPartner', name: 'Data Partner'},
    {value: 'Category', name: 'Category Rule'},
    {value: 'GeoCountry', name: 'Geo Location Country'},
    {value: 'GeoCity', name: 'Geo Location City'},
    {value: 'ImpressionAdvertiser', name: 'Advertiser (Viewer)'},
    {value: 'ImpressionCampaign', name: 'Campaign (Viewer)'},
    {value: 'ClickAdvertiser', name: 'Advertiser (Clicker)'},
    {value: 'ClickCampaign', name: 'Campaign (Clicker)'},
    {value: 'ConversionAdvertiser', name: 'Advertiser (Buyer)'},
    {value: 'ConversionCampaign', name: 'Campaign (Buyer)'}
];   
public audienceRuleTypes = RULE_ARRAY;
```

Comment: Can you add a working sample with: http://stackblitz.com ?

Comment: Why is your button a label ? What does `ruleOperatorArray` represents ? What is your goal, how do you want to achieve it ? Please post your whole code, not only pieces of code, that's blurry. And as @monogate said, please provide a [mcve] on stackblitz.

Comment: from this array which two item should removed ? is it dynamic or fixed two item has to be removed

Comment: Take two arrays, one "initial" and the other that at fisrt is a copy of "initial" (use copy=initial.slice()). To remove items use copy.splice(copy.length-2)

Comment: @monogate ok I will add.

Comment: @VickyKumar: item 5 and 6. Items are fixed.
        {value: 'GeoCountry', name: 'Geo Location Country'},
        {value: 'GeoCity', name: 'Geo Location City'},

Comment: @trichetriche goal is to added and remove two items when you click on different buttons. I will try to provide working version on stackblitz. There is a lot of code.

Comment: @Eliseo ok thank you, I will try.

Comment: And why would you remove 2 and append 2 items ? What is the purpose ? Does the user have to input somethign to filter the results ?

Comment: @trichetriche purpose is that when you use select "OR" rule(button) you shouldn't be able to choose 5 and 6 options from array. that "GeoCountry and GeoCity".
But if you chose "AND" rule operator you should be able to choose that all items and save some kind of form.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As i understood from your question is that you have below array

```
[
    {value: 'SimplePixel', name: 'Simple Pixel Call'},
    {value: 'SearchTerms', name: 'Search Terms'},
    {value: 'DataPartner', name: 'Data Partner'},
    {value: 'Category', name: 'Category Rule'},
    {value: 'GeoCountry', name: 'Geo Location Country'},
    {value: 'GeoCity', name: 'Geo Location City'},
    {value: 'ImpressionAdvertiser', name: 'Advertiser (Viewer)'},
    {value: 'ImpressionCampaign', name: 'Campaign (Viewer)'},
    {value: 'ClickAdvertiser', name: 'Advertiser (Clicker)'},
    {value: 'ClickCampaign', name: 'Campaign (Clicker)'},
    {value: 'ConversionAdvertiser', name: 'Advertiser (Buyer)'},
    {value: 'ConversionCampaign', name: 'Campaign (Buyer)'}
];
```

On some event you want 5th and 6th element to be removed so the resulting array will be

```
[
    {value: 'SimplePixel', name: 'Simple Pixel Call'},
    {value: 'SearchTerms', name: 'Search Terms'},
    {value: 'DataPartner', name: 'Data Partner'},
    {value: 'Category', name: 'Category Rule'},
    {value: 'ImpressionAdvertiser', name: 'Advertiser (Viewer)'},
    {value: 'ImpressionCampaign', name: 'Campaign (Viewer)'},
    {value: 'ClickAdvertiser', name: 'Advertiser (Clicker)'},
    {value: 'ClickCampaign', name: 'Campaign (Clicker)'},
    {value: 'ConversionAdvertiser', name: 'Advertiser (Buyer)'},
    {value: 'ConversionCampaign', name: 'Campaign (Buyer)'}
];
```

For that what i will suggest is to keep two array like this

```
export const STATIC-PART = [
    {value: 'SimplePixel', name: 'Simple Pixel Call'},
    {value: 'SearchTerms', name: 'Search Terms'},
    {value: 'DataPartner', name: 'Data Partner'},
    {value: 'Category', name: 'Category Rule'},
    {value: 'ImpressionAdvertiser', name: 'Advertiser (Viewer)'},
    {value: 'ImpressionCampaign', name: 'Campaign (Viewer)'},
    {value: 'ClickAdvertiser', name: 'Advertiser (Clicker)'},
    {value: 'ClickCampaign', name: 'Campaign (Clicker)'},
    {value: 'ConversionAdvertiser', name: 'Advertiser (Buyer)'},
    {value: 'ConversionCampaign', name: 'Campaign (Buyer)'}
]; 

export const DYNAMIC-PART = [
    {value: 'GeoCountry', name: 'Geo Location Country'},
    {value: 'GeoCity', name: 'Geo Location City'}
]
```

Now on the event when you you want larger array add the DYNAMIC-PART and use and when you want smaller array simply use static part

To add dynamic part try this code

```
const z = STATIC-PART.splice(4, 0, DYNAMIC-PART[0], DYNAMIC-PART[1]);
```

First parameter to splice indicates to change at 4th position 
Second parameter indicates how many item to remove for us it is 0
Rest other indicates items to be inserted
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice
Read more on splice